# Implicit / Explicit solution and Initial Value Problem - Differential Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

My text book has introduced short explanatory note as following:

"For given differential equation and its implicit solution, if you change it into a form of explicit one, there's a possibility the latter one would not satisfy the initial condition."

However, there's no example given.

Far now, I just had learned 1st-order differential equation which could be solved by separation of variables approach.

Any example falls into the above note?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider for example the DE
$$
y' = \frac{t}{y}, \quad y(1) = 2.
$$
Solving using separation of variables, we find that an implicit solution is
$$
y^2 = t^2 + 3,
$$
which indeed satisfies the initial condition. Now, rewriting as an explicit solution, i.e.
$$
y(t) = \pm \sqrt{t^2 + 3},
$$
we run into a problem, namely that we have two candidate solutions. However, note that the negative candidate gives $y(1) = -2$, which clearly violates the initial condition (I suspect this is what your text book is describing).

The positive solution satisfies our initial condition, hence the solution we are looking for is
$$
y(t) = \sqrt{t^2 + 3}.
$$

Comment: thx. I think your suspection is exact what it describes.

Comment: If that is what the author was hinting at, I would consider it bad writing at best. Actually, given the vagueness of the assertion, I think it's bad writing at any rate.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen I concur.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen I am still not that familiar to imagine the specific details when studying mathematics. Is there any recommended hint/know-how for me to be better at playing with math with fully alleged examples?

Comment: @Daschin Sorry, no easy answers to that one very general question! I can only give the standard answer: Practice math. And perhaps one more: Once you have tackled a problem, don't leap immediately into the next one, but spend some moments reviewing what you did. Where did you get stuck, if you did, and why? Can you think of a different way to arrive at the same answer? How does it fit into the surrounding landscape of similar problems? With time, mathematics will seem more like a unified whole instead of just a random collection of tricks.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen Thx for your valuable comment. I know the generality of the question might not fit to this site however, I need some advice who actually do math with their life. Last semester, I had learned introductory course regarding set-theory however, I had been overwhelmed by its depth of question. To learn and get the score from each courses, I am more tending to just concentrate on memorize the solution(such as in this case it would result in this/ or there's no possibility of asking this question since more advanced level had never been taught.. etc.)

Comment: (continue) but this kind of approach was helpful for me while I was in highschool but it looks more and more useless and something paradoxcially unpractical to actually utilize mathmatics. If you have experienced or see the student of yours who suffrered from similar problms, please let me advised.